# how to use color in arrays.xml file

Tags: android

I have items in my `arrays.xml` file, and I want only "Bravelle", "Cetrotide", and "Clomid" to use a blue color.  How can I get this?

```
<string-array name="medication_name">
    <item>Bravelle<sup>&#xae;</sup> (urofollitropin)</item>
    <item>Cetrotide<sup>&#xae;</sup> (cetrorelix acetate)</item>
    <item>Clomid<sup>&#xae;</sup> (clomiphene citrate)</item>
</string-array>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry. What? Paste your code from arrays.xml, do you mean using colors.xml? you want to reference this in another XML file?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<font color="#0000FF">` and the corresponding `</font>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<string-array name="medication_name">
    <item>Bravelle<font fgcolor="#ffff0000">red</font><sup>&#xae;</sup> (urofollitropin)</item>
    <item>Cetrotide<font fgcolor="#ffff0000">red</font><sup>&#xae;</sup> (cetrorelix acetate)</item>
    <item>Clomid<font fgcolor="#ffff0000">red</font><sup>&#xae;</sup> (clomiphene citrate)</item>
</string-array>
```